# RFID reader with RS232 gives wrong output

Tags: serial-port, rfid

Today i got [this reader](http://www.digitalas.lt/en/card-readers-controllers/376-emr-07-rs232-card-reader.html) from local shop. Earlier i worked with Wiegand type readers with no problem. So anyway, when i try to read EM type card with `0009177233` ID (written on card) i should get at least `9177233` with start and stop chars expected. But instead i get **50008C0891**

ASCII  `50008C0891`

HEX `02 35 30 30 30 38 43 30 38 39 31 0D 0A 03`

BIN `00000010 00110101 00110000 00110000 00110000 00111000 01000011 00110000 
00111000 00111001 00110001 00001101 00001010 00000011`

I use USB-RS232 converter and RealTerm software.

- Does anyone has any ideas why?
- Are there 2 ID's?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The decimal 9177233 equals HEX 8C0891, so the software gives you the serialnumber in hexadecimal notation. I think, the full number 50008C0891 is the 5 Bytes (40bit) from the UID of the EM-type chip.

Regards

Comment: Hmm... You are 100% right. I guess i panicked a bit :) Thanks a lot for a clearance